# How do I delete a file that PowerShell says does not exist?

Tags: powershell, delete-file

I added my Google Drive to my OneDrive and have a file in it that contains an invalid name (con.mp3). When I tried to remove the file (and the directory it is in), I get "Invalid File Handle". So I tried removing it with PowerShell as an Administrator.

Here is the directory listing showing the file, and the results of `Remove-Item` and `del`.

```
PS> dir

    Directory: C:\Users\Patrick\OneDrive\Google Drive\CW\CW.15WPM.VeryShortWords


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----        1/13/2018  11:49 AM         117069 con.mp3


PS> Remove-Item * -Force
Remove-Item : An object at the specified path C:\Users\Patrick\OneDrive\Google
Drive\CW\CW.15WPM.VeryShortWords\con.mp3 does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-Item * -Force
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-Item], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

PS> del *.*
del : An object at the specified path C:\Users\Patrick\OneDrive\Google Drive\CW\CW.15WPM.VeryShortWords\con.mp3 does
not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ del *.*
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-Item], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

How do I go about removing this file, so I can remove the directory? I tried removing it from Google Drive, but it didn't sync down to my computer.

Comment: I don't think this is anything specific to PowerShell but just a Windows / file system issue. For hints on how to delete such files, see: https://www.wikihow.com/Delete-Files-That-Cannot-Be-Deleted

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The reserved word `con` shouldn't be used as a path / file name (or part of).

You'll have to use the `-LiteralPath` parameter and eventually prefix with `\\?\`
when deleting.

So try:

```
Remove-Item -LiteralPath "\\?\C:\Users\Patrick\OneDrive\Google Drive\CW\CW.15WPM.VeryShortWords\con.mp3" -Force
```

If this doesn't work you can try in a cmd window:

```
Del "\\?\C:\Users\Patrick\OneDrive\Google Drive\CW\CW.15WPM.VeryShortWords\con.mp3"
```

If this doesn't help also read:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/320081/you-cannot-delete-a-file-or-a-folder-on-an-ntfs-file-system-volume

Comment: Del "\\?\C:\Users\Patrick\OneDrive\Google Drive\CW\CW.15WPM.VeryShortWords\con.mp3" worked like a charm. Thank you. I tried searching for anything to do with file can't be deleted, or 'invalid file handle' and never found the Microsoft Support article. I'll have to try to contact the person sharing the Google Drive and ask them to rename the file.

Comment: @PatrickDickey Thanks for feedback, I was just on the way to ask what solved the problem ;-)

Comment: I have been banging my head against a wall for two days. Thanks. Remove-Item -LiteralPath worked perfectly.

Comment: I also had this problem with a file named `nul` that I accidentally created from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you could try is to run the following CMD command `dir/A/X/P` and then run `del` command against listed MS-DOS short name. So the steps might be:

1. Open cmd.exe (command prompt)
2. Change a path to directory that contains the file `cd C:\Users\Patrick\OneDrive\Google Drive\CW\CW.15WPM.VeryShortWords`
3. Run `dir/A/X/P` to show MS-DOS short name
4. Delete the file using `del` command by it's **short ms-dos name**.

[image]